# Are they the same?

Tags: verbs, clauses

We usually define a verb of incomplete prediction as one not expressing a complete thought, hence its needing a complement. Thus, in the sentence "The baby seems", 'seems', being a verb of incomplete predication, requires a subject complement.

Now, if we consider the sentence " This is the house that Jack built", we say that 'Jack built' is a clause introduced by the relative pronoun 'that'. But the definition of a clause is that it's a part of a sentence with its own subject and predicate and expresses a complete thought. Doesn't the clause 'Jack built' seem to require, like verbs of incomplete predication, a complement to express a complete thought?

Comment: One special property of a relative clause is that it has a gap, a missing element. So the verb "built" doesn't have to have a complement because it is normal for a relative clause to have a gap.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "gap"? Is it a concept in linguistics or a general term in grammar?

Comment: The term GAP is widely used in modern reference grammars such as Huddleston & Pullum (2002, 2005). It is perhaps similar to the [empty category](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_category) or trace in generative grammar. GAP is just an element that missing in a clause. For example, "who are you talking to ___" — the complement of "to" is realized by a GAP.